# Print directory tree but exclude a folder on windows cmd

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, tree

I want to print a directory tree excluding a folder. I already know the basic way to print the tree like this:

```
tree /A > tree.txt
```

I want to achieve something like this:

```
tree /A [exclude folder node_modules] > tree.txt
```

Comment: The `tree` command does not support that functionality. Type `tree /?` from a command prompt to see what it does support.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The standard [`tree.com`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree) utility does *not* support excluding directories.

- If you only need to **exclude directories by name *themselves* and *not* also  *their entire subtree*** (child directories and their descendants), see [nferrell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43815420/45375).
- If you need to **exclude the *entire subtree* of directories matching a given name**, more work is needed - **see below**.

Below is the source code for PowerShell function `tree`, which emulates the behavior of `tree.com` command, while also:

- offering selective exclusion of subtrees by name
  Note: You may specify multiple names separated by `,` and the names can be wildcard patterns - note that they only apply to the directory *name*, however, not the full path.
- offering cross-platform support
  Note: Be sure to save your script with UTF-8 encoding *with BOM* for the script to function properly without `-Ascii`.
- offering switch `-IncludeFiles` to also print *files*.

With the function below loaded, the desired command looks like this:

```bash
tree -Exclude node_modules -Ascii > tree.txt
```

Run `tree -?` or `Get-Help tree` for more information.

---

##### `tree` source code (add to your `$PROFILE`, for instance; PSv4+):

```bash
function tree {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Prints a directory's subtree structure, optionally with exclusions.                        #'

  .DESCRIPTION
  Prints a given directory's subdirectory structure recursively in tree form,
  so as to visualize the directory hierarchy similar to cmd.exe's built-in
  'tree' command, but with the added ability to exclude subtrees by directory
  names.

  NOTE: Symlinks to directories are not followed; a warning to that effect is
        issued.

  .PARAMETER Path
  The target directory path; defaults to the current directory.
  You may specify a wildcard pattern, but it must resolve to a single directory.

  .PARAMETER Exclude
  One or more directory names that should be excluded from the output; wildcards
  are permitted. Any directory that matches anywhere in the target hierarchy
  is excluded, along with its subtree.
  If -IncludeFiles is also specified, the exclusions are applied to the files'
  names as well.

  .PARAMETER IncludeFiles
  By default, only directories are printed; use this switch to print files
  as well.

  .PARAMETER Ascii
  Uses ASCII characters to visualize the tree structure; by default, graphical
  characters from the OEM character set are used.

  .PARAMETER IndentCount
  Specifies how many characters to use to represent each level of the hierarchy.
  Defaults to 4.

  .PARAMETER Force
  Includes hidden items in the output; by default, they're ignored.

  .NOTES
  Directory symlinks are NOT followed, and a warning to that effect is issued.

  .EXAMPLE
  tree

  Prints the current directory's subdirectory hierarchy.

  .EXAMPLE
  tree ~/Projects -Ascii -Force -Exclude node_modules, .git

  Prints the specified directory's subdirectory hierarchy using ASCII characters
  for visualization, including hidden subdirectories, but excluding the
  subtrees of any directories named 'node_modules' or '.git'.

  #>

    [cmdletbinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
    param(
      [parameter(Position=0)]
      [string] $Path = '.',
      [string[]] $Exclude,
      [ValidateRange(1, [int]::maxvalue)]
      [int] $IndentCount = 4,
      [switch] $Ascii,
      [switch] $Force,
      [switch] $IncludeFiles
    )

    # Embedded recursive helper function for drawing the tree.
    function _tree_helper {

      param(
        [string] $literalPath,
        [string] $prefix
      )

      # Get all subdirs. and, if requested, also files.
      $items = Get-ChildItem -Directory:(-not $IncludeFiles) -LiteralPath $LiteralPath -Force:$Force

      # Apply exclusion filter(s), if specified.
      if ($Exclude -and $items) {
        $items = $items.Where({ $name = $_.Name; -not $Exclude.Where({ $name -like $_ }, 'First') })
      }

      if (-not $items) { return } # no subdirs. / files, we're done

      $i = 0
      foreach ($item in $items) {
        $isLastSibling = ++$i -eq $items.Count
        # Print this dir.
        $prefix + $(if ($isLastSibling) { $chars.last } else { $chars.interior }) + $chars.hline * ($indentCount-1) + $item.Name
        # Recurse, if it's a subdir (rather than a file).
        if ($item.PSIsContainer) {
          if ($item.LinkType) { Write-Warning "Not following dir. symlink: $item"; continue }
          $subPrefix = $prefix + $(if ($isLastSibling) { $chars.space * $indentCount } else { $chars.vline + $chars.space * ($indentCount-1) })
          _tree_helper $item.FullName $subPrefix
        }
      }
    } # function _tree_helper

    # Hashtable of characters used to draw the structure
    $ndx = [bool] $Ascii
    $chars = @{
      interior = ('├', '+')[$ndx]
      last = ('└', '\')[$ndx]                                                                #'
      hline = ('─', '-')[$ndx]
      vline = ('│', '|')[$ndx]
      space = ' '
    }

    # Resolve the path to a full path and verify its existence and expected type.
    $literalPath = (Resolve-Path $Path).Path
    if (-not $literalPath -or -not (Test-Path -PathType Container -LiteralPath $literalPath) -or $literalPath.count -gt 1) { throw "'$Path' must resolve to a single, existing directory."}

    # Print the target path.
    $literalPath

    # Invoke the helper function to draw the tree.
    _tree_helper $literalPath

  }
```

---

Note:

- The third-party [`Get-PSTree`](https://github.com/santisq/PSTree) cmdlet (installable via `Install-Module PSTree -Scope CurrentUser`, for instance) offers a more fully featured implementation that notably includes reporting (cumulative) directory *sizes* (though no support for *excluding* directories as of this writing).

Comment: @mklement0 This code only prints the folders. How to print the all the files in the folders including hidden files.

Comment: @PankajMahato: Yes, the code originally printed just folders, given that's what the standard `tree.com` utility does too. However, I've just added the `-IncludeFiles` switch, which now allows you to print _file_ names as well. As before, `-Force` includes hidden items.

Comment: This just gives me Too many parameters - <FolderNameToBeExcluded>; Any ideas? Tried on both CMD and PowerShell.

Comment: @anand_v.singh: The error message implies that you ran `C:\WINDOWS\system32\tree.com`, from CMD. What _this_ answer does is to define a _PowerShell function_ named `tree` - which you have to define in your session first - which emulates `tree.com`'s behavior _while also adding new features_ and therefore supporting _additional parameters_.

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell, just use Where-Object and exclude the folder names you want (put a `*` wildcard on the front since it can be difficult to know how many spaces and special characters are on the same line as the folder name):

`tree /A | Where-Object {$_ -notlike "*node_modules"} > tree.txt`

Edit: This won't exclude subfolders though, it will only exclude the folders you name in the Where-Object clause.

Comment: it didn't exclude its subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly a complete answer, but should allow you to accomplish what you want with a little work. If you used the `Show-Tree` code from the [PowerShell Community Extensions](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Pscx) as a base, and then added in something to filter out folders, you could accomplish what you desire. This is something that should be totally doable, really, since this little bit of code shows how to define a string to exclude (wildcards accepted in a `-like` format), then get a recursive folder structure and denote if that is an excluded folder, or is contained within an excluded folder.

```
$DirExcludes = @()
$ToExclude = 'temp*'
GCI -Recurse -Directory |%{
    Switch($_){
        {$_.Name -ilike $ToExclude} {
            $DirExcludes += $_.FullName;
            Write-Host $_.FullName -ForegroundColor Red
            Continue}
        {$DirExcludes -and $_.FullName -match "^($(($DirExcludes|%{[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'))"} {
            Write-Host $_.FullName -ForegroundColor DarkRed
            Continue
            }
        default {Write-Host $_.FullName -ForegroundColor Blue}
    }
}
```

When I ran this against my user profile it showed that it caught both a 'Temp' folder and a 'Template' folder, and marked those and each subfolder of those to be excluded. You should be able to get the code of the `Show-Tree` command by doing:

```
Get-Command Show-Tree -ShowCommandInfo | % Definition
```

Then you would just need to devise how to incorporate something similar to what I have above into that code, and you can make a new function to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Save this code below and run:

```
import os

def generate_folder_structure(path, exclusions, output_file):
    with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for exclusion in exclusions:
                if exclusion in dirs:
                    dirs.remove(exclusion)
            level = root.replace(path, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
            f.write('{}{}/\n'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root)))
            subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
            for file in files:
                f.write('{}{}\n'.format(subindent, file))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    base_path = r'C:\Users\awy\repos\databricks-dp-lib'
    exclusions = ['venv']
    output_file = 'folder_structure1.txt'
    generate_folder_structure(base_path, exclusions, output_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`PSTree` Module](https://github.com/santisq/PSTree) (**Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of this Module) you can exclude files and folders using its [`-Exclude` Parameter](https://github.com/santisq/PSTree/blob/main/docs/en-US/Get-PSTree.md#-exclude), as an example before and after:

```bash
PS ..\PSTree> pstree .\src\PSTree\ -RecursiveSize

   Source: C:\Users\User\Documents\PSTree\src\PSTree

Mode            Length Hierarchy
----            ------ ---------
d----        326.81 KB PSTree
-a---        931.00  B ├── ExceptionHelpers.cs
-a---          4.09 KB ├── PathExtensions.cs
-a---        442.00  B ├── PSTree.csproj
-a---        900.00  B ├── PSTreeCache.cs
-a---          1.06 KB ├── PSTreeDirectory.cs
-a---          1.66 KB ├── PSTreeExtensions.cs
-a---        517.00  B ├── PSTreeFile.cs
-a---        399.00  B ├── PSTreeFileSystemInfo.cs
-a---          1.61 KB ├── PSTreeFileSystemInfo_T.cs
-a---        626.00  B ├── PSTreeIndexer.cs
d----        186.37 KB ├── obj
-a---         12.05 KB │   ├── project.assets.json
-a---        642.00  B │   ├── project.nuget.cache
-a---          2.12 KB │   ├── PSTree.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json
-a---          1.10 KB │   ├── PSTree.csproj.nuget.g.props
-a---        534.00  B │   ├── PSTree.csproj.nuget.g.targets
d----         82.03 KB │   ├── release
d----         82.03 KB │   │   └── netstandard2.0
d----         87.92 KB │   └── Debug
d----         87.92 KB │       └── netstandard2.0
d----          1.15 KB ├── Internal
-a---          1.15 KB │   └── _FormattingInternals.cs
d----          6.43 KB ├── Commands
-a---          6.43 KB │   └── GetPSTreeCommand.cs
d----        120.72 KB └── bin
d----         54.43 KB     ├── release
d----         54.43 KB     │   └── netstandard2.0
d----         66.28 KB     └── Debug
d----         66.28 KB         └── netstandard2.0

PS ..\PSTree> pstree .\src\PSTree\ -RecursiveSize -Exclude *obj, *bin

   Source: C:\Users\User\Documents\PSTree\src\PSTree

Mode            Length Hierarchy
----            ------ ---------
d----         19.72 KB PSTree
-a---        931.00  B ├── ExceptionHelpers.cs
-a---          4.09 KB ├── PathExtensions.cs
-a---        442.00  B ├── PSTree.csproj
-a---        900.00  B ├── PSTreeCache.cs
-a---          1.06 KB ├── PSTreeDirectory.cs
-a---          1.66 KB ├── PSTreeExtensions.cs
-a---        517.00  B ├── PSTreeFile.cs
-a---        399.00  B ├── PSTreeFileSystemInfo.cs
-a---          1.61 KB ├── PSTreeFileSystemInfo_T.cs
-a---        626.00  B ├── PSTreeIndexer.cs
d----          1.15 KB ├── Internal
-a---          1.15 KB │   └── _FormattingInternals.cs
d----          6.43 KB └── Commands
-a---          6.43 KB     └── GetPSTreeCommand.cs

PS ..\PSTree>
```

The module also offers a [`-Include` Parameter](https://github.com/santisq/PSTree/blob/main/docs/en-US/Get-PSTree.md#-include) for *inclusive filtering* and other features.

If you want to try it out it can be easily installed through the PowerShell Gallery:

```
Install-Module PSTree -Scope CurrentUser
```