# Exclude Windows folder in CMD Search

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am fairly new to Batch files but this is my Batch File for displaying path for Jpegs, Mp3, Mp4 etc.

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d C:\
Echo
echo Files Paths :
dir /b *.mp3 /s
dir /b *.mp4 /s
dir /b *.jpg /s
endlocal
pause
```

1.) Is there anyway that I can exclude Microsoft and Windows (wallpapers, icons, sounds, etc) folder from my search?

2.) How do I save the results in this output file (which is already created) C:\output.txt

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print directory tree but exclude a folder on windows cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810090/print-directory-tree-but-exclude-a-folder-on-windows-cmd)

Comment: As the previously mentioned duplicate, is for an non requested tag/scripting language, the simplest non `PowerShell` method would be to use the `/V` option with `Find` or `FindStr`, _but doing so may not be the quickest_. Perhaps you'd be better off with filtering the directories to be searched at the outset, by nesting a `For` loop inside another, with the outer one filtering the directories and the inner recursively searching what it returns.

Comment: Simplest would be to do dir with findstr. `dir /b /s *.mp3 | findstr /vi "microsoft" | findstr /vi "windows`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite an easy task for the [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html):

```cmd
dir /S /B /A:-D *.mp3 *.mp4 *.jpg | findstr /V /I /C:"\\Microsoft\\" /C:"\\Windows\\" > "C:\output.txt"
```

The `\\` represent one literal `\` in order to ensure that only directories become excluded whose full names match the predefined names. Since `findstr` uses the `\` as an escape character `\\` is necessary.

As you can see it is not necessary to use multiple [`dir` commands](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html). The filter option `/A:-D` excludes any directories to be returned even if they match one of the given patterns.

The returned data is written to a file using [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html). To append to the file rather than overwriting it replace `>` by `>>`.