# How to use "tree" command on powershell to show files as well as directories

Tags: powershell, tree, filesystems, hidden-files

I am trying to get full structure of my project in tree format in powershell.
When I use the command `tree`, it only shows directories and subdirectories, but neither files nor hidden folders, such as `.git`

How can I show files as well?

Thank you

Comment: might be of interest: https://github.com/santisq/PSTree

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree)

Comment: Have you tried to take a look to the help? `tree /?`

Comment: @Olaf - Thank you, tree /F works, it shows all files, also hidden file, such as .gitignore, but do not show hidden folder, such as .git, but it has solved my problem. thank you

Comment: The Windows `tree.com` utility _never_ shows _hidden_ file-system items (irrespective of whether they're files or directories). On Windows, a name starting with `.` does _not_ make an item hidden - it is solely the `Hidden` file/directory _attribute_ that controls default visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tree.com`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tree):

- *does* have an option to include *files* in the output: `/F`
- does *not* have an option to include *hidden* directories and files - they are *invariably excluded*.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

**Solutions**:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43810460/45375) contains an custom PowerShell function named `tree` that extends the functionality of `tree.com` and whose `-Force` switch allows you to include hidden items.
- The `Get-PSTree` cmdlet from the third-party [`PSTree`](https://github.com/santisq/PSTree) module (install with, e.g., `Install-Module PSTree`) also supports `-Force` and offers even more features.

---

<sup>[1] I'm referring to files and directories *on Windows* that have the `Hidden` attribute, which is unrelated to whether their names start with `.` (e.g., `.gitignore`; it is only on *Unix*-like platforms that the latter are automatically considered hidden). You can set the `Hidden` attribute with `attrib +H someDir`, for instance, and clear it with `attrib -H someDir`. `tree.com` does *not* show such hidden items.</sup>